# Save username, and display on other pages

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I am having difficulty in setting up a way to capture the username for display on other pages. This code authenticates and creates new users on an azure easy table.

```
public int IsAuth { get; set; }

    //[DataTable("User_Cred")]
    public class User_Cred
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }



   private IMobileServiceSyncTable<User_Cred> todoGetTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<User_Cred>();



    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        if (!App.MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
        {
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("CIS4910C-DB");
            store.DefineTable<User_Cred>();
            await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
        }
        await SyncAsync();
    }

    private async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        await todoGetTable.PullAsync("User_Cred", todoGetTable.CreateQuery());
    }



    async public void submitAuthBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();

        GetAuthentication();

    }

    async public void GetAuthentication()
    {
        try
        {

            //IMobileServiceTable<User_Cred> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<User_Cred>();

            List<User_Cred> items = await todoGetTable
                .Where(User_Cred => User_Cred.Username == textBoxUsername.Text)
                .ToListAsync();

            IsAuth = items.Count();



            // Return a List UI control value back to the form

            foreach (var value in items)
            {

                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Welcome Back  " + value.Username);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(home));
            }


            if (IsAuth > 0)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("You are Authenticated");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();


            }
            else
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(" Account Does Not Exist, please Register to get Started.");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: " + em.Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    async private void submitAuthBtn_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            User_Cred itemReg = new User_Cred
            {
                Username = textBoxUsername.Text,
                Password = textBoxPassword.Text

            };
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<User_Cred>().InsertAsync(itemReg);
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Thank you for Registering! Now just hit log in");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: " +em.Message);

            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Having asked before, I was only able to get several mutations of this code that didnt work. Any suggestions or edits are appreciated. This was on the main page, but couldn't be read by the next code block on my next page.

```
public string globalUserLabel;

public void SaveSetting(string userLabel, string userNamelabel)
{
    globalUserLabel = userLabel;
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    //Saving your setting  
    localSettings.Values[userLabel] = textBoxUsername.Text;
}
```

The next page had

```
public home()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    UserNameLabelBox.Text = ReadSetting(MainPage.globalUserLabel );
}



private string ReadSetting(string userLabel)
{
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    //Reading and returning your setting value
    var value = localSettings.Values[userLabel];
    if (value != null)
        return value.ToString();
    else
        return userLabel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `userLabel` value is the same when you store the value as when you try to retrieve it. It is usually advisable to use a `const string` field for this. Even better, refactor all code which accesses settings to a separate class. You can create properties for individual settings and use their name as the key to the setting:

```
public class AppSettings
{
   public string UserName
   {
      get => ReadSetting(null);
      set => SaveSetting(value);
   }

   private string ReadSetting(string defaultValue,
                             [CallerMemberName]string settingKey = null)
   {
       var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
       if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(settingKey))
       {
            return (string)settings.Values[settingKey];
       }
       else
       {
            return defaultValue;
       }
   }

   private string SaveSetting(string value, 
                             [CallerMemberName]string settingKey = null)
   {
       ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[settingKey] = value;
   }
}
```

Now you will just use `AppSettings` in your code:

```
public void SaveSetting(string userLabel, string userNamelabel)
{
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    appSettings.UserName = textBoxUsername.Text;
}


private string ReadSetting(string userLabel)
{
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    return appSettings.UserName ?? "User not signed in";
}
```

To further explain the code - `[CallerMemberName]` is a special attribute, which is filled out during compilation and will contain the name of the caller of the method, in this case it will be the property name.

In addition, `AppSettings` is now a simple service, which can be used as a singleton and you could extract an interface from it and inject it wherever you need to use it using an IoC container.